# Visual Studio 2008 build fails with no error output

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

When building my VS2008 C# project on windows 7, I get this output:

```
------ Build started: Project: C:\...\OutsideWeb\, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
Validating Web Site
Building directory '/OutsideWeb/js/'.
Building directory '/OutsideWeb/'.

Validation Complete
------ Build started: Project: C:\...\InsideWeb\, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
Validating Web Site
Building directory '/InsideWeb/js/'.
Building directory '/InsideWeb/'.

Validation Complete
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 2 failed, 3 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

If I build with the web.config file open, I get lines and lines of these messages.  Just noticed this a few minutes ago.

> Message    1   Could not find schema information for the element 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0:configuration'.  C:\iis\inetpub\WWWRoot\SQLEmergencyRequest\InsideWeb\Web.config 2   2   C:...\InsideWeb\

**I get no errors or warnings and the project doesn't start.**  Can anyone point me to a helpful log file to get going?

Comment: let me make sure whether i get it, if you build the project with the (web.config) file closed, the project build and run normally??

Comment: There are additional warnings with the web.config open, but it will not run either way.

Comment: Rebuild but change configuration first (x86 instead of Any CPU).

Comment: could you post some more information ? such as the project file .csproj or web.config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstalling VS2008 and reinstalling did the trick.  2 hours of time, but less that I've spent messing with this so far.

Answer (score 5):

Difficult to say with the info provided (the schema issues in the web.config are a nuisance, but they aren't the problem).

Go to Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run

The drop down labeled "MSBuild project build verbosity" is probably set to Minimal. Change it to Normal or Detailed and you will likely get better information in the output window during the build. This may lead you to your real issue.

Comment: Yes, I saw that tip online as a resolution to a lack of output, but that didn't show anything when set on the highest setting of diagnostic.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar error and it went away when I deleted the '.suo' file and restarted the machine.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the first answer

Go to Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run

Turn the logging up to Normal or better to get more output. If you are seeing some issue when the web config file is open then leave it open and execute a build.

Now go to the View->Other Windows->Output. Make sure that "Build" is selected in the "Show output from:" combo box. Scroll to the top of the output and put your cursor at the top of the window. Press CTRL->F to bring up the "Quick Find" window. Make sure that "Look In" is set to "current window", if "current window" isn't available try pinning the output window so that it will be always open.

Now you are set to do a search of the output from the top of the output window. Search for "error " (the space is important). From the output window you can double click a line and it will take you to the code that corresponds with the error found.

Comment: I have posted the entirety of the output window for the build in my original post.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar error after updating the project files from Clear Case. I checked error list in VS2008, where i found that some library files are missing.

After updating complete package and Config Spec of Clear Case, the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

have you checked the warnings tab?
sometimes it has useful information,  such as when you miss a reference of a project, you get an non-related build error, but when you check the warning tab, you will figure out that there is a reference missing.

Comment: If you're referring to the warnings contained in the error list window, then yes, I've checked that.

Answer (score 0):

I remember having a similar error. I had to go into the last reported folder, then iteratively open the code behind files, and use Resharper to tell me about any errors.

Painful, but eventually I got the build working.

We later on ended up with lots of 'circular reference' errors on user controls.

Now I just let Cruise Control build my web site, and have batch=true on the compilation element in web.config

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s10awwz0.aspx

Comment: Hi,  I got resharper.  Not sure what you mean by the "last reported folder".

Comment: I ran an analysis on the entire project with resharper and found two compiler error which are now fixed.  Still getting the same error though.

Answer (score 0):

Dear [people from the future](http://xkcd.com/979/):

I had the same problem in VS 2010 and none of these other answers worked for me, even after cleaning the solution, restarting VS, etc. Posted my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14532673/957950), but wanted to link it under this question as it came up first on my search.