# VS2010 Project doesnt build but doesnt show any errors or warnings

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

Im stumped: `0 Errors, 0 Warnings, 0 Messages` but  the `output` window says
 `Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 1 Failed, 0 Skipped`

I have two projects, `A` is a web application, `B` is a dll referenced by `A`. `B` by its self builds ok.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Do you mean `B` is referenced in your web app ?

Comment: Does this work for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068011/visual-studio-2010-says-build-failed-with-no-errors-after-i-change-a-source-file

Comment: There's really no message in the output window, nor in the error list? Did it just suddenly stop working? Do you have problems building any project or it's just this one?

Comment: Its just the Web App that gives that error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I excluded the `App_Readme` folder from the project and it started building. Not sure why I have to exclude the folder though. The folder was added when i added Glimpse from NuGet.

Answer (score 1):

In  `*.sou` file there is user preferences and most of time if you change directory(downloading project ) of project those remains unchange. Even some time migration doesn't work properly.So simply deleting `*.suo` file and re opening project will solve in most cases. Cleaning all bin directories may also help. If none help I think moving project to another place and repeat the steps above will help.

In your situation I think excluding the file cause an override on `*.suo` file best guess.

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen to me too.  The problem was I had the following code

```
Sub Page_UnLoad()  Handles Me.UnLoad
    objConn.Close()
    objConn = Nothing
End Sub
```

I removed the Page_UnLoad Sub and it compiled and ran as expected.