# Any time I change a project in VS2013, the build fails with no errors

Tags: .net, windows, visual-studio-2013, build

Yes, I've read this Q/A ([Visual Studio 2010 says Build failed with no errors after I change a source file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068011/visual-studio-2010-says-build-failed-with-no-errors-after-i-change-a-source-file)) and no it didn't help.

Same basic problem though, except I'm using VS2013 on Windows 8.1.

Any time I get latest from source control, or add a file to the project, the build fails and I have ZERO errors. It doesn't matter which solution I'm in (I have multiple projects at work) they all act the same way.

If I restart VS, the problem goes away until the next time I get latest or add a file to a project.

I've tried deleting the .suo files, deleting the bin folder, moving the project. No Bueno.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a repair on VS2013 has eliminated the problem.